# Merge excel sheets and workbooks identifying the sheet and workbook source VBA

Tags: vba, excel, merge, identity

I have multiple workbooks and worksheets with the same information, I've been trying to merge all this files identifying the information source (Worksheet - workbook).

I've used this code but it just merge the cells and I could not identify the information source (worksheet - Workbook)

```
Sub merge()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each hoja In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If hoja.Name = "todas" Then hoja.Delete
Next
Sheets.Add before:=Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "todas"
For x = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(x).Select
Range("a1:o" & Range("a650000").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
Sheets("todas").Range("a650000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 
Paste:=xlValues
Next
Sheets("todas").Select
End Sub
```

This is one of the libraries I have to merge:

[image]

Comment: `Sheets(x).PARENT.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not have your workbook so I could not test it myself, but the structure is there so you can debug it easily if you ran into an error:

```
Sub merge()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each hoja In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If hoja.Name = "todas" Then hoja.Delete
    Next
    Sheets.Add before:=Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "todas"

    For x = 2 To Sheets.Count
        Set rng = Sheets(x).UsedRange
        rng.Copy

        'Cell in column A after the last row
        Set cell = Sheets("todas").Range("a650000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        cell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        'Define the range that just got pasted (only column A)
        Set rng = cell.Resize(rng.Rows.Count, 1)

        'Offset it to the column next to the last column
        Set rng = rng.Offset(0, rng.Columns.Count)

        rng.Value = Sheets(x).Name 'paste the name ofthe sheet in each row
        Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1)
        rng.Value = Sheets(x).Parent.Name 'paste the name of the workbook in each row

    Next
    Sheets("todas").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your help, this help me identifying the workbook and worksheet, but you know how i could add to the code to merge different workbooks?

Comment: Do you want to merge all of the open workbooks, or workbooks in a folder?

Comment: You just need to loop through the files in the folder using DIR function and then use the code that I wrote to stack them together in one sheet. Practically, write the code in an independent workbook and copy the excel files in the same folder and run the code from the workbook, it should open the excel files one after another collecting the data from each sheet and each excel file. Start something and if you got into a problem you can always get help here. Look for DIR functions examples to get an idea of how to structure your main sub